# Twilio: How to present a Customer Number to a third participant on a Conference Call?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

We have a solution in which our company has partnered with a 3rd party sales provider to transfer calls to them. We receive leads from customer's input on our website, call the customer through creating a conference call, then transfer by join a 3rd party sales agent to finish the sale. Our 3rd party have requested we send the customer's number when we do the transfer, however, Twilio does not allow this as the customer's number is not part of the verified list of numbers. 
The means provided by Twilio to overcome this is to verify the number programatically, but we cannot do this as Twilio makes a call to the custom requesting a 6 digit code. How can we modify this to do the verification for the customer without interrupting precious time for us to complete a sale.

Comment: this seems like a technical support inquiry about a 3rd party product, and also does not seem to be programming related.

Comment: Can you add the call code to the question?

Comment: @Claies, thank you. Yes it was a product related issue. By default Twilio does not allow this to prevent prank or fraud calls.